# Looping array data from database

Tags: php, odbc

I have a little problem with looping odbc_fetch_array in php script...
problem is second: I have some data in my DB, and i want to search special data in it... I get data into array throught `$row = odbc_fetch_array('$array')`, but I am stucked only at last record in this row...
So i want to know how to print all data from this array...

here is my php code:

```
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($surnames))
                {
                    echo json_encode($row);

                    /*$f_name = trim(odbc_result($surnames, "F_NAME"));
                    $s_name = trim(odbc_result($surnames, "S_NAME"));*/

                    //getting birthdate from personal id
                    $bd = trim(odbc_result($surnames, "PERS_KOD"));

                    $day = substr($bd, 0, 2);
                    $month = substr($bd, 2, 2);
                    $year = substr($bd, 4, 2);

                    $birthdate = $day.".".$month.".".$year;

                    $table = "
                                <table>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Surname</th>
                                    <th>Birth Date</th>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>".$row['f_name']."</td>
                                        <td>".$row['s_name']."</td>
                                        <td>".$birthdate."</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                             "; 
                    $data['result']['table'] = $table;
                }
```

**EDIT1**

here is `echo` inside while

`json_encode(tr)<tr><td>ALEVTINA       <\/td><td>KARPOVA                       <\/td><td>14.07.27<\/td><\/tr>"null"json_encode(tr)<tr><td>DACE           <\/td><td>KARPOVA                       <\/td><td>08.10.77<\/td><\/tr>"nullnullnull"json_encode(tr)<tr><td>OLGA           <\/td><td>KARPOVA`

and here is `var_dump` outside while

`array(65) {
  [0]=>
  string(89) "<tr><td>GA�INA         </td><td>KARPOVA                       </td><td>08.03.56</td></tr>"`

**EDIT2**

maybe there is a problem on my html page, where I am getting back this table? here is the code `$.ajax ({ data: { action: "search_patient_surname", surname: inserted_surname }, success: function(a) { console.log(a);  if (a.errors.length > 0) { //vivodit input_error.val(a.errors.join(' | ')); } $('#Persons').html(a.result.table); }     });`

Comment: Does your `json_encode($row)` print multiple rows?

Comment: @vinodadhikary, yes it prints many rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `$data['result']['table']` is getting overwritten on every iteration leaving you will the last record.

Also I assume you want one table with multiple rows not multiple tables.

Try this:

```
$result_tr = array();
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($surnames))
{
    echo json_encode($row);

    /*$f_name = trim(odbc_result($surnames, "F_NAME"));
    $s_name = trim(odbc_result($surnames, "S_NAME"));*/

    //getting birthdate from personal id
    $bd = trim(odbc_result($surnames, "PERS_KOD"));

    $day = substr($bd, 0, 2);
    $month = substr($bd, 2, 2);
    $year = substr($bd, 4, 2);

    $birthdate = $day.".".$month.".".$year;

    $tr = "<tr><td>{$row['f_name']}</td><td>{$row['s_name']}</td><td>{$birthdate}</td></tr>";
    $result_tr[] = $tr;
}

$table = "";
if (!empty($result_tr)) {
    $table = "<table><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th><th>Birth Date</th>";
    foreach ($result_tr as $row) {
        $table .= $row;
    }
    $table .= "</table>";
}

$data['result']['table'] = $table;
```

Comment: thanks.. but I can't understand, why I am getting $result_tr[] empty... because $tr is not empty...

Comment: It shouldn't be empty.  Can you post the output of one of the `tr` inside the loop and post `var_dump($result_tr)` outside the loop

Comment: here is echo of $tr inside while()

`null"\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>ALEVTINA       <\/td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>KARPOVA                       <\/td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>14.07.27<\/td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/tr>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t  "null"\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>DACE           <\/td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>KARPOVA `

here is var_dump outside while - `array(0)`

Comment: Can you try that again.  I changed the formatting because `\t` and `\r\n` made it difficult to read.  Also what are nulls, are they output of `json_encode`?

Comment: here is `echo` inside while

`json_encode(tr)<tr><td>ALEVTINA       <\/td><td>KARPOVA                       <\/td><td>14.07.27<\/td><\/tr>"null"json_encode(tr)<tr><td>DACE           <\/td><td>KARPOVA                       <\/td><td>08.10.77<\/td><\/tr>"nullnullnull"json_encode(tr)<tr><td>OLGA           <\/td><td>KARPOVA      `

and here is `var_dump` outside while

`array(65) {
  [0]=>
  string(89) "<tr><td>GA�INA         </td><td>KARPOVA                       </td><td>08.03.56</td></tr>"`

Comment: as I can understood, that's meanst that all is good.. but I still have table:null(empty table)

Comment: can you see my edit's in my queston... I put there some code @vinodadhikary